# Can i use Jsoup in Jetpack Compose in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In traditional xml way , i use GlobalScope.launch{}  with  runOnUiThread {} to work with Jsoup.But in jetpack Compose this not work anymore. It just instant closed when run it.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        GlobalScope.launch{

            val url="somewebsite.com"
            var doc= Jsoup.connect(url).get()

          runOnUiThread {
          }
        }

        setContent {
            WannaJsoupTheme {

                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is running a coroutine related to using JSoup? Are you using JSoup as an HTTP client? Also, please provide some code to show exactly what doesn't work, and in which way it doesn't work. For instance, do you have a compile error, or an exception at runtime?

Comment: thx for your reply i have added some code on my question

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**Explanation**

Based on the above code, apparently you're using the main thread to perform I/O operations. Main thread are generally used for `user interface` operations. It's better to use background threads for `I/O operations`. - They are `more efficient`.

Here's demo app which I created to demonstrate use of JSoup with MVVM architecture.

Link - https://github.com/TheCodeMonks/NYTimes-App

Solution - https://gist.github.com/Spikeysanju/111e061ad82f3b7be6beb419fb18bca4

**Quick Solution**

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        
        // Initiate Coroutine scope
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        var text by remember {
            mutableStateOf("")
        }

        JsoupTheme {
            // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
            ) {

                // Initiate coroutine scope will will run on IO thread &  write method to get the text from the website
                scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    val url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Jobs"
                    Jsoup.connect(url).get().also {
                        text = it.text()
                    }
                }

                // Fetch result from the state variable [Text]
                Text(text = "Result: $text")

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thx for your answer with so much detail and i actually installed your app and look the code before i post the question, but too complicated for me.  thanks

Comment: It's a bad practice to launch a coroutine directly in scope of composable function - it's gonna repeat the action on each recomposition, which may happen up to once a frame with animations. At least you should use `LaunchedEffect` in this case, which is still gonna be repeated on configuration change, e.g. screen rotation, more info can be found in side effects [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects)

Comment: thx i will check this .I also noticed that when i try to return a list by "val list =remember { mutableStateListOf<String>() } " from GlobalScope my app keep crushing.